# NoSuchMethodError when getting display properties using: Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight() in LWJGL

Tags: java, exception, lwjgl

I'm trying to get the display properties for my display using: `Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();` and `Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();` but I get the following error:

```
[LWJGL] Version: 3.2.0 build 12
[LWJGL]      OS: Windows 7 v6.1
[LWJGL]     JRE: 1.8.0_151 amd64
[LWJGL]     JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM v25.151-b12 by Oracle Corporation
[LWJGL] Loading library (system): lwjgl
[LWJGL]     Using SharedLibraryLoader...
[LWJGL]     Found at: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\lwjgl.dll
[LWJGL]     Loaded from org.lwjgl.librarypath: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\lwjgl.dll
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil accessor: MemoryAccessorUnsafe
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil allocator: DebugAllocator
[LWJGL] Loading library: glfw
[LWJGL]     Using SharedLibraryLoader...
[LWJGL]     Found at: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\glfw.dll
[LWJGL]     Loaded from org.lwjgl.librarypath: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\glfw.dll
[LWJGL] Loading library (system): lwjgl_opengl
[LWJGL]     Using SharedLibraryLoader...
[LWJGL]     Found at: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\lwjgl_opengl.dll
[LWJGL]     Loaded from org.lwjgl.librarypath: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12\lwjgl_opengl.dll
[LWJGL] Loading library: opengl32
[LWJGL]     opengl32.dll not found in org.lwjgl.librarypath=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgluser\3.2.0-build-12
[LWJGL]     Loaded from system paths: C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwInit()I
    at org.lwjglx.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:17)
    at org.lwjglx.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:74)
    at Engine.DisplayRenderEngine.DisplayManager.getWidth(DisplayManager.java:255)
    at Engine.EntityHandeling.BasicEntityRenderer.prepare(BasicEntityRenderer.java:40)
    at Engine.DisplayRenderEngine.DisplayManager.updateDisplay(DisplayManager.java:167)
    at Engine.Core.RenderThread.render(RenderThread.java:167)
    at Engine.Core.RenderThread.run(RenderThread.java:104)
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the min api you are using?

Comment: I believe I downloaded 3.2 but I'm not quit certain. How can I check that?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem by replacing:

```
Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

with:

```
IntBuffer w = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(4);
IntBuffer h = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(4);
glfwGetWindowSize(window, w, h);
height = h.get(0);
```

and:

```
Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
```

with:

```
IntBuffer w = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(4);
IntBuffer h = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(4);
glfwGetWindowSize(window, w, h);
width = w.get(0);
```

This fixes the problem.